# Generating all possible combinations of filling a fixed vector with 2 values in Julia

Tags: vector, statistics, julia, combinations

I am wanting to generate an iteratable that can calculate all possible ways to fill a vector with binary values. It would be preferred to be iterable as I then require to apply selection criteria before storing the vector inside a matrix.

E.g if the vector was size 4 then there is 16 possibilites
[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,1],[0,1,1,1] etc.

I have tried using Combinatorics.jl as outputting as an iteratable seems ideal but it always seems to remove the degenerate arrangements which is not something I want.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77336166/combinatorics-variations-not-combinations (the answer there can also be used here)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Iterators.product` for this, which returns the cartesian product of its arguments. It returns an iterator, on which you can apply `Iterators.filter` or whatever else, before materializing it.

```
julia> Iterators.product(fill([0, 1], 4)...) |> collect
2×2×2×2 Array{NTuple{4, Int64}, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 (0, 0, 0, 0)  (0, 1, 0, 0)
 (1, 0, 0, 0)  (1, 1, 0, 0)

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 (0, 0, 1, 0)  (0, 1, 1, 0)
 (1, 0, 1, 0)  (1, 1, 1, 0)

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 (0, 0, 0, 1)  (0, 1, 0, 1)
 (1, 0, 0, 1)  (1, 1, 0, 1)

[:, :, 2, 2] =
 (0, 0, 1, 1)  (0, 1, 1, 1)
 (1, 0, 1, 1)  (1, 1, 1, 1)
```

You can obtain this as a linear vector with the `vec` function, and you can convert the inner tuples into vectors (if needed) with a broadcasted `collect` over them. So:

```
julia> function twoones(n)
         p = Iterators.product(([0, 1] for _ in 1:n)...)
         # just an example selection criteria: combinations with exactly two 1's in them
         q = Iterators.filter(v -> count(!iszero, v) == 2, p)
         return collect.(vec(collect(q)))
       end
twoones (generic function with 1 method)

julia> twoones(4)
6-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 1, 0, 0]
 [1, 0, 1, 0]
 [0, 1, 1, 0]
 [1, 0, 0, 1]
 [0, 1, 0, 1]
 [0, 0, 1, 1]
```